# How to read a json file into a C++ string

Tags: c++, json, string, fstream

My code like this:

```
std::istringstream file("res/date.json");
std::ostringstream tmp;
tmp<<file.rdbuf();
std::string s = tmp.str();
std::cout<<s<<std::endl;
```

The output is `res/date.json`, while what I really want is the whole content of this json file.

Comment: You have to open the file, then read its contents into a `std::string`.

Comment: Should use ifstream, not istringstream.

Comment: Use `ifstream`, not `istringstream`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This

```
std::istringstream file("res/date.json");
```

creates a stream (named `file`) that reads from the string `"res/date.json"`.

This

```
std::ifstream file("res/date.json");
```

creates a stream (named `file`) that reads from the file named `res/date.json`.

See the difference?

Answer (score 4):

I found a good solution later. Using `parser` in `fstream`.

```
std::ifstream ifile("res/test.json");
Json::Reader reader;
Json::Value root;
if (ifile != NULL && reader.parse(ifile, root)) {
    const Json::Value arrayDest = root["dest"];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < arrayDest.size(); i++) {
        if (!arrayDest[i].isMember("name"))
            continue;
        std::string out;
        out = arrayDest[i]["name"].asString();
        std::cout << out << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I have the `Json::Reader` in my c++ project?

Answer (score 3):

Load a `.json` file into an `std::string` and write it to the console:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int, char**) {

    std::ifstream myFile("res/date.json");
    std::ostringstream tmp;
    tmp << myFile.rdbuf();
    std::string s = tmp.str();
    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My json parser fails using this method, but If I write the json text directly to a string by hand, it works... what is this doing with the text format?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the stuff above but the thing is they dont work in C++ 14 for me :P
I get stuff like from ifstream `incomplete type is not allowed`on both answers AND 2 json11::Json does not have a `::Reader` or a `::Value` so Answer 2 does not work either I thin the answoer for ppl who use this https://github.com/dropbox/json11 is to do something like this:

```
ifstream ifile;
int fsize;
char * inBuf;
ifile.open(file, ifstream::in);
ifile.seekg(0, ios::end);
fsize = (int)ifile.tellg();
ifile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
inBuf = new char[fsize];
ifile.read(inBuf, fsize);
string WINDOW_NAMES = string(inBuf);
ifile.close();
delete[] inBuf;
Json my_json = Json::object { { "detectlist", WINDOW_NAMES } };
while(looping == true) {
    for (auto s : Json::array(my_json)) {
        //code here.
    };
};
```

Note: that is is in a loop as I wanted it to loop the data.
Note: there are bound to be some errors with this but at least I opened the file correctly unlike above.